# How to use flatten setting in webpack 5 copy-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, copy-webpack-plugin

I use copy-webpack-plugin 10.2.0 and webpack 5.65.0. I want to copy js file in `public/js` folder to `dist/js`.

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns:[
            {
                from:'public/js/*.js',
                to:path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist','js'),
            
            }
        ]
    })
],
```

But the setting also copy the path into dist, and it becomes `dist/js/public/js`.I try to add `flatten:true` but it has error

```
Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options.patterns[0] has an unknown property 'flatten'. These properties are valid:
   object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, filter?, transformAll?, toType?, force?, priority?, info?, transform?, noErrorOnMissing? }
```

How to make it then ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the filename in the `to` parameter using the `[name]` and `[ext]` components and simply omit the `path` part.

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns:[
            {
                from:'public/js/*.js',
                to:path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist','js', '[name][ext]'),
            
            }
        ]
    })
],
```